# I sent some ETH from MyEtherWallet almost 11 hours ago and it still pending

Tags: myetherwallet

Tx Hash  `0xa4bade1a1dd4c8b6b2c76dfe2a7051abe2215c83db77e5029cd725fd64fcfbb5`
Gas Limit 21000
Gas Price 20 Gwei

Will it eventually gets processed?

Answer (score 0):

It might or might not. According to https://ethgasstation.info/, the lowest gas to ensure transferring safely is 21 Gwei as of writing (though I would prefer 40 Gwei the suggested standard). 20 Gwei might not guarantee the transfer.

Comment: It's not really about guarantee or not. It's more like a miner will accept your transaction or not. Low gas price -> Less miner that will accept your transaction.

Comment: is there anything i can do or i just wait until it times out? How long it takes to times out? Do I get my ETH back to my wallet when it times out?